# Safe to not specify revisions with SVN merge?

Tags: svn

What is the difference between

```
cd trunk
svn merge -r<revision where branch was cut>:<revision of trunk> svn://path/to/branch/branchName
```

and

```
cd trunk
svn merge svn://path/to/branch/branchName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly nothing.

Since SVN 1.5 svn will retrieve revisions based on its merge tracking feature. So if you do not give a revision it figures out from which revision you created the branch and will start on this revision unil current HEAD revision.

Note: If you issue this command twice, the second time it will not merge again, as each revision is already tracked as merged.

Comment: Hello Sir, could you please take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36157555/3287204)? Thanks in advance ... :)